# Событие отправки письма при регистрации пользователя

Tags: php, битрикс

День добрый!
Нужно чтобы при регистрации (например при условии что пользователь с Москвы) - Битрикс отправлял ещё одно письмо
в public_html/local/php_interface/init.php
добавил

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAfterUserRegister", "OnUserEmailLoginRegisterHandler");

function OnUserEmailLoginRegisterHandler(&$arFields)
{
    if ($_SESSION['MOSCOW_SESSION']==true){ // проверяем город
        $toSend = Array();
        $toSend["EMAIL"] = $arFields["EMAIL"];
        $toSend["LOGIN"] = $arFields["LOGIN"];
        $toSend["NAME"] = $arFields["NAME"];
        $toSend["LAST_NAME"] = $arFields["LAST_NAME"];
        CEvent::Send("NEW_USER_M", "s1", $toSend, "N", 108); //NEW_USER_M - тип почтового события, 108 - id шаблона
    }
}
```

Но отправка письма не происходит (даже если убрать проверку на "Москву").
Как можно проверить это событие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странное дело, но сброс кеша сайта решило эту проблему.
Код полностью рабочий